# Django Query how to display a count of records with a distinct dates and display date and count

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a Django query that as output will give me a list of dates and the count of records against those dates.

This is my current query which gives me a count of distinct dates as {'dates':2}

```
        stats =  models.SearchResultStat.objects.values().filter(organisation=organisation.id).annotate(date=TruncDate('created')) \
            .values('date') \
            .distinct() \
            .aggregate(dates=Count('date'))
```

But what I need is

```
[{'2020-11-01' : 2},{'2020-11-02' : 1}]
```

How do I achieve this?

**Added Model**

```
class SearchResultStat(models.Model):
    search = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=250)
    organisation = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Show your model

Comment: How about to use window functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

The ORM based approach:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
from django.db.models import Count

SearchResultStat.objects.annotate(
        date=TruncDate('created')
    ).values('date').annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by()
```

The other option is to use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(SearchResultStat.objects.all().values_list('created__date', flat=True))
```